# How do I query the Store API in a specific language

Tags: shopware, shopware6-app, shopware6-api

I use PWA with only one language - German (but in Shopware I have two languages Eng and Ge). The problem with an error message from `/checkout/cart/*` endpoints are that they are only in English.

[image]

I tried to add the sw-language-id header, change the language of the sale channel, change snippets, and edit snippet sets but nothing worked. It looks like this part is hardcoded if it's true how can I solve this problem by myself?

I have an idea to create my plugin which will decorate `/checkout/cart/*` endpoints.